# how to get the full tweet of the user timeline with twitter4j?

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I want to get tweets from certain user timelines using java library twitter4j, currently I have source code which can get ~ 3200 tweets from user time line but I can't get full tweet. I have searched in various sources on the internet but I can't find a solution to my problem. anyone can help me or can anyone provide an alternative to get a full tweet from the user timeline with java programming?

my source code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
    ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
      .setOAuthConsumerKey("aaa")
      .setOAuthConsumerSecret("aaa")
      .setOAuthAccessToken("aaa")
      .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("aaa");
    TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
    Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();

    int pageno = 1;
    String user = "indtravel";
    List statuses = new ArrayList();
    while (true) {
        try {
            int size = statuses.size();
            Paging page = new Paging(pageno++, 100);
            statuses.addAll(twitter.getUserTimeline(user, page));
            System.out.println("***********************************************");
            System.out.println("Gathered " + twitter.getUserTimeline(user, page).size() + " tweets");

            //get status dan user
            for (Status status: twitter.getUserTimeline(user, page)) {
                //System.out.println("*********Place Tweets :**************\npalce country :"+status.getPlace().getCountry()+"\nplace full name :"+status.getPlace().getFullName()+"\nplace name :"+status.getPlace().getName()+"\nplace id :"+status.getPlace().getId()+"\nplace tipe :"+status.getPlace().getPlaceType()+"\nplace addres :"+status.getPlace().getStreetAddress());
                System.out.println("["+(no++)+".] "+"Status id : "+status.getId());
                System.out.println("id user : "+status.getUser().getId());
                System.out.println("Length status :  "+status.getText().length());
                System.out.println("@" + status.getUser().getScreenName() +" . "+status.getCreatedAt()+ " : "+status.getUser().getName()+"--------"+status.getText());
                System.out.println("url :"+status.getUser().getURL());
                System.out.println("Lang :"+status.getLang());
            }
            if (statuses.size() == size)
                break;
        }catch(TwitterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Total: "+statuses.size());
}
```

**Update :**
After the answer given by @AndyPiper

**the my problem is every tweet that I get will be truncated or not complete. a tweets that I get will be truncated if the length of tweet more than 140 characters. I found the reference [tweet_mode=extended](https://gist.github.com/nishemon/8618f0eb8cb78e6dcfe6217a7e7cb24b), but I do not know how to use it. if you know something please tell me.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Twitter API limits the timeline history to 3200 Tweets. To get more than that you would need to use the (commercial) premium or enterprise APIs to search for Tweets by a specific user.

Comment: thank you for the answer Mr. Andy, but my problem is not getting tweets more than 3200. my problem is every tweet that I get will be truncated or not complete. a tweets that I get will be truncated if the length of tweet more than 140 characters. I found the reference (see link below), but I do not know how to use it. if you know something please tell me.

Link: https://gist.github.com/nishemon/8618f0eb8cb78e6dcfe6217a7e7cb24b

Comment: I see - that means you need to add `tweet_mode=extended` to your API call  to getUserTimeline to retrieve the full length Tweets. I think this is implemented in the property file for Twitter4J 4.0.6. There will be a `full_text` field in the response.

Comment: this works for java project. but it does not work for javafx with fxml. I am beginner in using javafx and fxml, do you know twitter4j 4.0.6 can be used for javafx. Thank you @AndyPiper

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with that combination.

Comment: it's okay your answer is very helpful for me, thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

Your Configuration should be like this:

```
ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
  .setOAuthConsumerKey("aaa")
  .setOAuthConsumerSecret("aaa")
  .setOAuthAccessToken("aaa")
  .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("aaa")
  .setTweetModeExtended(true);
```

It is explained well [here](https://nmatpt.com/blog/2018/01/06/twitter4j-extended-mode/)

Answer (score 0):

if you are streaming tweets

fist: you have to add .setTweetModeExtended(true); into your configurationbuilder

second(here is the code)

```
       TwitterStream twitterStream = new TwitterStreamFactory(cb.build()).getInstance();
    StatusListener listener = new StatusListener(){
        public void onStatus(Status status) {

            System.out.println("-------------------------------");

            if(status.isRetweet()){
                System.out.println(status.getRetweetedStatus().getText());
            }
            else{
                System.out.println(status.getText());
            }`
```

its totally works for me.
take care yourself :)

Answer (score -1):

If you are implementing twitter api using twitter4j.properties file and getting truncated timeline text value,simply add the below property in it at the end.
tweetModeExtended=TRUE